# Can someone explain "Fake it till you make it" approach in Test Driven Development?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I have a problem to understand the evolution of code when you have taken the "Fake It Until You Make IT" TDD approach.

Ok, you have faked it, let's say you returned a constant so that the broken test is green in the beginning. Then you re-factored your code. Then you run the same test which is going to pass obviously because you have faked it!

But if a test is passing how can you rely on that, especially when you know that you faked that?

How should the faked test be refactored with your real code refactoring so that it can still be reliable?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW if you adopt this strategy I strongly recommend you use a developer productivity tool such as Jetbrains Resharper as it will greatly speed up your ability to do this.

Comment: A single constant returned from a method is technically the simplest way to make a test succeed.  However, you are more than likely going to have multiple corroborating tests for any method, and it will take more than a constant to pass them all.

Answer (score 6):

You first create a unit test testing new functionality that does not exist.

Now, you have a unit test to a non existing method. You then create that method that doesn't do anything and your unit test compiles, but of course, fails.

You then go on building your method, underlying functionality etc until your unit test succeeds.

That's (kind of) test driven development.

The reason you should be able to trust on this is that you should make your unit test so that it actually tests your functionality. Of course, if it just returns a constant and you just test on that, you have a problem. But then, your unit test is not complete.

Your unit tests should (in theory) test every line. And if you've done that OK, this should work.

Comment: A unit test shouldn't test every line. A method with a failure condition will have a test just for that condition, and additional tests for each additional success/failure condition. Thus few tests, even in theory, will ever test every line.

Comment: What I mean with "every line" is code coverage. I know what you mean, but I think all these terms are relative because 100% code coverage technically means every line. Of course it's not possible to check for the existence of every line of code in your code, but you are testing whether the code you expect to be there, is there. Changed "test" to "tests" :).

Comment: @PietervanGinkel There are many kind of metrics for code coverage, you are referring to statement coverage. 100% code coverage does not need to mean every line. 

This answer is a description of TDD, but is does not touch the "fake it until you make it"-strategy used in TDD.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: write *more* tests.

If the method is returning a constant (when it should be calculating something), simply add a test for a condition with a different result.  So, let's say you had the following:

```
@Test
public void testLength()
{
    final int result = objectUnderTest.myLength("hello");
    assertEquals(5, result);
}
```

and `myLength` was implemented as `return 5`, then you write a similar (*additional*) test but pass in `"foobar"` instead and assert that the output is 6.

When you're writing tests, you should try to be very vindictive against the implementation and try to write something that exposes its shortcomings.  When you're writing *code*, I think you're meant to be very *laissez-faire* and do as little is required to make those nasty tests green.

Comment: But it sounds like Triangulation than 'Fake it till you make it' pattern, don't you think so?

Comment: I think Triangulation and Fake it Till You Make It are related.  FITYMI is "do the simplest thing that could possibly work".  When you write your first test case, the simplest thing is to just return the right answer.  yay!  We got a passing test.  Are we done?  Clearly not, because if the whole implementation were that simple we probably not even be writing it and instead just using a constant.  Fake it till you make it just helps you get bootstrapped and get on with the next test that fleshes out the system.  I may use "Fake it" for the first test, but it rarely survives the 2nd or 3rd test.

Answer (score 5):

Fake it 'til you make it says to write the simplest possible thing to pass your current tests.  Frequently, when you've written a single test case for a new feature, that simplest possible thing is to return a constant.  When something that simple satisfies your tests, it's because you don't (yet) have enough tests.  So write another test, as @Andrzej Doyle says.  Now the feature you're developing needs some logic to it.  Maybe this time the simplest possible thing is to write very basic if-else logic to handle your two test cases.  You *know* you're faking it, so you know you're not done.  When it becomes simpler to write the actual code to solve your problem than to extend your fake to cover yet another test case - that's what you do.  And you've got enough test cases to make sure you're writing it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This may be referring to the practice of using mocks/stubs/**fakes** with which your system/class under test collaborates.

In this scenario, you "fake" the collaborator, not the thing that you are testing, because you don't have an implementation of this collaborator's interface.

Thus, you fake it until you "make it," meaning that you implement it in a concrete class.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable answer. Not only you may not have implemented the collaborator, it may even be harmful to use it in a testing environment. Think of interacting with a real database for example.

Answer (score 0):

In TDD, all the requirements are expressed as tests. If you fake something and all tests pass, your requirements are fulfilled. If this is not giving you the expected behavior, then you have not expressed all your requirements as tests.

If you continue faking stuff at this point, you will eventually notice that the easiest solution would be to actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you refactor the code, you are switching from returning a constant value to returning an expression in terms of variables, which are derived/calculated.

The test, assuming it was written correctly the first time around, would still be valid for your newly refactored implementation and does not have to be refactored.

It's important to understand the motivation behind Fake It: It's similar to writing the Assert first, except for your production code. It gets you to green, and lets you focus on turning the fake into a valid expression in the simplest way possible while still passing the test. It's the first thing to try when implementation is not obvious, before you give up and switch to Triangulation.